# What are the options to deploy add-ins outside of the store?

Tags: office365, add-in

I know there is a possibility to build an app library in SharePoint for all users on that Office 365 tenant. But some customers do not use an Offie365 tenant at all, and not all add-ins are suitable for store distribution. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a re basically four options indeed. There are the two you've mentioned: the SharePoint library and the Office store. But other than that there are two other ones as well. In the new Admin Center preview for Office 365 you can distribute add-ins to all users in a tenant (this is actually very similar to the SharePoint catalog). On top of that, there is the ability to sideload which is different for the different clients:

- On an iPad you can sideload add-ins through iTunes.
- On the Office web clients you can (since recently) upload your manifest directly in the add-in dialogue.
- On the Office desktop Clients (except for Outlook) you can put your manifests on a share and add this share to your trusted catalog ([see here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the several post on Stack Overflow, it seems you were developing Office add-in.

[Payment options for Office add-ins in the Office store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043924/payment-options-for-office-add-ins-in-the-office-store)

[Login into Office 365 tenant from within Office add-in without pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043213/login-into-office-365-tenant-from-within-office-add-in-without-pop-up)

You can use one of several methods to deploy your Office Add-in for testing or distribution to users:

[Sideloading](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins.htm) - Use as part of your development process to test your
   add-in running on Windows, Office Online, iPad, or Mac.

[SharePoint catalog](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog.htm) - Use as part of your development process to test
   your add-in, or to distribute your add-in to users in your
   organization.

[Office 365 admin center preview](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-Ins-in-Office-365-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) - Use to distribute your add-in to
   users in your organization.

[Office Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff075782-1303-4517-91cc-b3d730e9b9ae%28Office.15%29.aspx) - Use to distribute your add-in publicly to users.

And [here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish) is an helpful article about deploy Office add-in: