# Login into Office 365 tenant from within Office add-in without pop-up

Tags: authentication, office365

If I want to access an Office 365 API in and Office add-in I have to use the Azure AD login screen in my application. However, this will always result in a pop-up for the login action itself. Is there a way to prevent his pop-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you're looking for is a way to make sure that the external domain (where the Azure AD login screen is hosted, something like https://login.microsoftonline.com for Office 365 users) is showed within the same add-in frame rather than launching a popup frame. While there actually s a way to do this using the appdomains tag in your add-in manifest (see [AppDomains](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomains)).

While this works for most, it is actually not a best practice because many organizations use federated logins for their Azure AD, which means they have their own login screen domains. Wile you could theoretically add them all there is no way of knowing in advance what the domain is going to be, so for the time being a pop-up is a necessary evil and a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the Dialog API. See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.md