# Payment options for Office add-ins in the Office store

Tags: office365, office-addins

We want to develop an add-in for several of the Office applications, we want the end-user to pay for these add-ins. We're not sure how to go about licensing and payment options. There should be some limited options for payment in the Office Store, but how we would check licenses in that case is unclear to me. Would it also be possible (or rather: allowed) to have our own (or a third party) licensing and payment system in the add-in? What would generally be the best option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are valid. You can either make use of the payment services provided by the Office store or use your own that is secured with an account to login for example. To learn more about the Store provided options you should take a look at the [Licensing Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163257.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that helps you in generating and validating licenses using an API provided by Microsoft. More info on the pricing in general can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456317.aspx).